# Automatically Unsubscribe consumers from does not click "opt in" checkbox

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, landing-page, unsubscriber, publicationlist

I have a Data extension in MC that it is completed with information that comes when filling in a landing page.
The smart capture has an "opt in" checkbox. People who check the "opt in" will then receive email communications and people who dont click the "opt in" button will have to be automatically "unsubscribed" from my publication list asociated to this Data extension.The question is, how can I automatically change the status in my Publication list of subscribers who dont opt in?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in [Automation Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_automation_studio_activities.htm&type=5) using a series of activities.

1. **[SQL Query](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5)**: Select the records you want to unsubscribe from the
   Publication List and add/overwrite to a new Data Extension.
2. **[Data Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_a_data_extract_activity.htm&type=5)**: Extract the data and use the external key from the Data Extension used as the SQL output. Name the file to be created, this will be the same name used in the next step for import.
3. **[Import File](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_an_import_activity.htm&type=5)**: Using the same name as the file created in the Data Extract, import this file into your Publication List. Be sure to map the fields appropriately and depending on how your account is set up, lists will require certain attributes to successfully import.

**Example SQL**:

```
 select SubscriberKey, EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName, 'Unsubscribed' as Status
 from SmartCapture_DE
 where optin != 'true'
```

Add these activities to an automation and set it to run daily, weekly or whichever timing interval is required for your specific needs.

My experience with Smart Capture forms hasn't been great, it only allows for adding new records which is not ideal in most cases. I tend to use [DEManager](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_demanager.htm&type=5) which supports add/update.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: @GuadalupeInesTapia Did this work?

Comment: Hi! @Kyle Szabo it was missing between data extract and import activity, a file transfer activity. It did work adding that activity! If needed we can share with you more details. Thanks for your help!